# Need to search an array of strings

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of Strings in vb which I am searching using the contents of an excel cell.
One of the cell values will contain an '&' character, e.g. 'Shipping & Receiving'
How do I search for & character?

If I replace both the array value and all the cell values with 'and', the search works.   In practice unfortunately, I won't be able to do that.

Comment: Can you show us the code you have?

Comment: You can search for `Chr(38)` to just find the `&` symbol, but I feel like this isn't what you really need. It's not exactly clear what you are looking to do here - code would help